# How to delete auxillary/satellite objects from a central object?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, object-mode

So I've imported the TwinBlast mesh from unreal engine into blender. For some reason they way they setup the mesh, his two guns and grenade are overlapped on the floor between his feet. You can easily move them and separate them from each other in pose mode, but when ever you go to edit mode they snap back to the original position which is on the ground overlapped.

Im basically trying to delete one of the guns and the grenade which, in object mode, are considered apart of the entire model.

Is it possible to delete these in object mode when you can move them away from each other and clearly see them? I have 2 pictures for clarity and reference.
Thanks.

[image: object mode]

[image: edit mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they aren't individually selectable, they're not deletable separately in object mode.  They're probably part of the same object, weighted to their own bones.

If they're weighted to their own bones, you have a few options.  One is to pose the model and enter weight paint mode (ctrl-tab from object mode), then switch to vertex select mode ('v' key) and ctrl-RMB lasso a whole bunch of vertices from the object you want to delete, now that it's nicely out of the way.  When you tab into edit mode, those vertices will still be selected, and you can ctrl-l select linked to probably get the whole object for easy deletion.  If not, delete, tab back to weight paint, rinse and repeat until you've got it all.

Another deal is that probably all of the vertices of the individual objects are exclusively weighted to a single bone.  Select one vert in edit or weight paint mode, 'n' to open your properties shelf, and look at the vertex weights section.  Here it will tell you which vertex group this vert belongs to; clicking on the group will select that vertex group for your model.  Now you can look on the properties view, under data vertex groups, and hit the "select" button, which will grab all the vertices assigned to this particular vertex group.  Which is probably the entire object, and only the entire object.  Delete, and you're good.

Comment: yeah exatly what i was looking for. Thank you kindly!